# Scoping issue occurring when looping through a tryCatch block in R

Tags: r, scope, try-catch

I'm trying to loop through a vector, evaluate each member in a conditional statement, and record any false evaluations onto an external csv. However, the argument i keeps triggering an error in the code below. Specifically, my output is "1234567891011" and then the error `"Error in cat(i) : object 'i' not found"` interrupts execution. I suspect that there is some sort of scoping issue, but I'm baffled as to what it could be. A reproducible example is included below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library('utils')

tryBlock <- function(i){
  cat(i)
  if(i>10)
     stop("condition is false")
}

work <- function(list){
  for(i in list){
    tryCatch(tryBlock(i),
             error= function(err){write.table(as.data.frame(c(i,err)), "falseOutput.csv")})
}}

work(1:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when trying to write an object of class

```
c("simpleError", "error", "condition")
```

to a CSV file. Or even to a text file with `write.table`. When I tried to use `writeLines` I forgot that there is no `append` argument so only the last error, with `i == 20`, would be written.

The solution I found is to output to file with `cat`.
Note that `err` is coerced to `"character"`.

```
work <- function(list){
  for(i in list){
    tryCatch(tryBlock(i),
             error = function(err){
               msg <- paste("iter:", i, "\n")
               msg <- c(msg, paste("error:", as.character(err), "\n"))
               cat(msg, file = "falseOutput.txt", append = TRUE) 
             }
    )
  }
}

work(1:20)
#1234567891011121314151617181920
```

The first lines of the file are:

> iter: 11
>   error: Error in tryBlock(i): condition is false
>
> iter: 12
>   error: Error in tryBlock(i): condition is false
>
> iter: 13
>   error: Error in tryBlock(i): condition is false

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the solution! Do you know why the improper use of the write.table function would prevent other functions from accessing i? On the face of it, it seems like these would be unrelated problems (however, clearly they aren't).

Comment: @e4a I am not sure but I believe it's a stack issue, last in, first out. The `write.table` error is the last one so it's the first to be processed. And immediately after execution stops.